# how to access call detail records via asterisk rest api?

Tags: asterisk

I have the call detail records stored on my local server. I have been looking at the documentation online for asterisk, but I can't find anything on how to access the data from my web app (hosted on the cloud) using their rest api. Anyone got it working? Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Asterisk store cdr into database(for example you can use mysql)

After that you can write simple php or other language rest api to access database data.

No, asterisk not store cdr in asterisk pbx deamon, so you can't request cdr data using asterisk rest api.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a plugin or tutorials to make the api? I'd rather not make it myself

Comment: Also, what about the Asterisk Manager Interface? Can I not use that one?https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239

Comment: AGAIN. Asterisk NOT STORE cdr record. You can create simple pluging yourself. It have just access database. Since you say you full stack programmer, it have not take more then 15 minutes for you.

Comment: indeed I am a full stack programmer, so you got me there! It will certainly take more than 15 minutes, but I get your point. I'll give it a try and accept your response unless I find something totally off. Regards.